# Filtering Gridview with stored procedure in textboxchanged event

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, gridview, textchanged

I want the gridview filtered on every value I write to the textbox. I have a stored procedure for searching. But it is not working.

This is my event:

```
protected void TXT_SEARC_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connect.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("search_information", connect);
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", TXT_SEARC.Text.Trim());

    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[search_information]
  @x NVARCHAR(50)
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM Workstation$ 
  WHERE [WKSNAME] LIKE '%'+@x+'%'
     OR SERVICETAG LIKE '%'+@x+'%'
     OR LOCATION LIKE'%'+@x+'%'
     OR MODEL1 LIKE '%' + @x + '%'
     OR DEPARTMENT LIKE '%' + @x + '%'
     OR DETAILS LIKE '%' + @x + '%'
     OR USER LIKE '%' + @x + '%'
```

I have no error but this event is not working. Nothing happens in gridview when I try to write to the textbox.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, I would advice editing your question and adding relevant information to it. It is a desktop application (winforms/WPF,gtk#) or a web one (asp.net core, MVC, webforms)? Its a major difference it handles events different ways. Another advice: Do some debugging, set a breakpoint, see if the code is executed. It will help you a lot and let you provide a more concrete question and allow others help you better.

Comment: It is asp.net application

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in your debugger? Did your `TXT_SEARC_TextChanged` get executed? If it did, does `TXT_SEARC.Text` contain what you typed?

Comment: Yes I used breakpoint. TXT_SEARCH.Text does not contain what I write. When I used the same code in WindowsFormApplication it works. I don't understand.

Comment: Related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: At the moment, your code does not reproduce your problem. You are probably assigning a value to your textbox in `Page_Load` event, but events do cause postbacks, and your Page_Load code is executing more times than you wanted. Check `Page.IsPostback` property. It is a XY problem (your problem is why you textbox does not have what your typed, not your function code nor your stored procedure).

Comment: Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57919789/edit) to edit your question, add better tags to your question and a better description of your problem.